# How is the CSS Selector & and > used inAngularJS CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, css-selectors, sass

I have a css file. In my rails project I could something like this in my css file

```
.ls-brighter {
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:12px;
      background-color: #FF6600;
      padding: 1%;
      font-style:italic;
      & > span {
        color:red; 
        font-size:1.6rem;
      }
    }
```

but if i try it in AngularJS css file, it always returns a lexical error.

How are CSS selectors used in AngularJS?

Comment: What do you mean by "AngularJS css file" ?

Comment: Do you mean `ngStyle`?

Comment: The clue is in your question's tags. Presumably, Angular styles are vanilla CSS only.

Comment: @enguerranws a css file in my angularjs project

Comment: this is the JSFiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/boyfunky/78yqgakw/ and this is the targeted output that i am trying to get http://loanstreet.com.my/calculator/home-loan-and-entry-cost-calculator but on the '&' and '>' it keeps telling me that there is a lexical error

Comment: Vanilla CSS does not support nesting — that syntax you have in your code likely belongs to a CSS preprocessor (SCSS/SASS, that is).

Comment: Cannot reproduce with vanilla Sass, but the `&` is redundant here.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice you are doing Sass (Scss syntax) here. Maybe "normal" CSS would be fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ls-brighter {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:12px;
  background-color: #FF6600;
  padding: 1%;
  font-style:italic;
  & > span {
    color:red; 
    font-size:1.6rem;
  }
}
```

This is not CSS, this is Sass. **`&` and nesting are not used in CSS.**

Try this CSS version :

```
.ls-brighter {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:12px;
  background-color: #FF6600;
  padding: 1%;
  font-style:italic;

}
.ls-brighter > span {
    color:red; 
    font-size:1.6rem;
  }
```

Comment: thnks enguerranws didnt know about that.

Comment: Maybe you should learn standard CSS before using preprocessors ? It could help in many cases.

Comment: yah thnks @enguerranws. I managed to get it sorted out by integrating sass into my gruntfile but then the css effects not showing any changes. here is the plunkr file. can u help me? http://plnkr.co/edit/x1Ai9ynZuZclP11VEV0m